# How can I access docker daemon from within a docker container?

Tags: docker

I am deploying an application with docker, and I need to use docker commands from a container. How can I use docker commands from a docker container?

Comment: I wanted to restart some containers from containers. I got an answer, you can see it in my answer. thanks @RoVo for you help.

Comment: might help https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/10/introduction-to-docker-and-containerization/

Answer (score 3):

Found several way to do it. You can mount your docker daemon socket in container, as below.

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ; bash"
```

if you are using docker-compose then you can mount using Volumes.

```
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Could you please add the command on how to run a container then from within the other container ?

Comment: you will be able to access all docker commands withing container as you do on host.